# Template to Bind non-member static function alongside with member function

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I have a class that stores Dispatched commands in a queue and invokes them later. Command processor is a template class `Encoder`, it uses its method `Encoder::Encode` to process a command. But it can be either a member or a static non-member function. **How can I bind it?**

```
// specialization that have deduced Encoder's arguments
template <class Encoder, typename ... ArgsT>
class SerialCommunicator<Encoder, std::tuple<ArgsT...>>
{

    // ...
    Encoder encoder_;
    std::queue<std::function<EncodeResult(QByteArray&)> commands_;
    mutable std::mutex commandsMutex_;

public:
    // ...

    void Dispatch(ArgsT ... args)
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lg{commandsMutex_};
        commands_.emplace(std::bind(&Encoder::Encode, &encoder_, std::placeholers::_1, 
                std::forward<ArgsT>(args)...);
    }

    // ...
};
```

With C++17 I would be able to use `if constexpr(std::is_member_function_pointer_v<&Encoder::Encode>)` block to pass a pointer to `Encoder` in case we deal with a member function pointer.

Comment: Can't static member function be called with the object instance? -- "To refer to a static member m of class T [...]: [...] member access expression E.m or E->m, where E is an expression that evaluates to T or T* respectively. " -- https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static

Comment: @user202729 it surely can. But static function has a different type than a member function. Hence you can't call `std::bind` with a pointer to an object.

Answer (score 0):

Not very elegant solution using SFINAE

```
template<typename FuncPtr, typename T,
        bool = std::is_member_function_pointer<FuncPtr>::value>
struct bind_func
{
    template<typename ... Args>
    static auto bind(FuncPtr fPtr, T *pObj, Args &&... args)
    {
        return std::bind(fPtr, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
};

template<typename FuncPtr, typename T>
struct bind_func<FuncPtr, T, true>
{
    template<typename ... Args>
    static auto bind(FuncPtr fPtr, T *pObj, Args &&... args)
    {
        return std::bind(fPtr, pObj, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
};

template<typename FuncPtr, typename T, typename ... Args>
auto bind_func_v(FuncPtr funcPtr, T *pObj, Args &&... args)
{
    return bind_func<FuncPtr, T>::bind(funcPtr,
                    pObj, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```